# EF vs EF Core on Saving Related Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, navigation-properties

I have two related entities as shown below

```
public partial class Student{
   public int StudentId{ get; set; }
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   public ICollection<Subject> Subjects{get;set;}
}

public partial class Subject{
   public int SubjectId{ get; set; }
   public int StudentId{ get; set; }
   public string SubjectName{ get; set; }
   public Student Student{ get; set; }
}
```

In EF6 I could save these related objects as follows and works fine.

```
var student = new Student{
Name = "John Doe"
}

_dbContext.Sudents.Add(student);

var subjects = new List<Subject>{
new Subject{StudentId = student.StudentId, SubjectName = "Math"},
new Subject{StudentId = student.StudentId, SubjectName = "Biology"}
}

_dbContext.Subjects.AddRange(subjects);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

The above code didn't work in EF Core as StudentId in Subject entity always doesn't have value.

To be able to save in EF Core I have to to as below

```
var subjects = new List<Subject>{
new Subject{SubjectName = "Math"},
new Subject{SubjectName = "Biology"}
}

var student = new Student{
Name = "John Doe",
Subjects = subjects
}

_dbContext.Sudents.Add(student);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

What has been changed in EF Core so that I have to change syntax in order to save these related entities?

Answer (score 0):

You can't obtain StudentId by just adding a student to the context. You can get the key only after running SaveChanges. This is why your first example is not working properly. But it will work if you change the code to this

```
var student = new Student{
Name = "John Doe"
}

_dbContext.Sudents.Add(student);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();

var subjects = new List<Subject>{
new Subject{StudentId = student.StudentId, SubjectName = "Math"},
new Subject{StudentId = student.StudentId, SubjectName = "Biology"}
}

_dbContext.Subjects.AddRange(subjects);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

or (thanks for a hint to  @SvyatoslavDanyliv) you can try to assign the whole student instance instead  of studentId

```
var student = new Student{
Name = "John Doe"
}

var subjects = new List<Subject>{
new Subject{Student=student, SubjectName = "Math"},
new Subject{Student = student, SubjectName = "Biology"}
}

_dbContext.Subjects.AddRange(subjects);
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

In this case you can call SaveChanges only once too.

Comment: I haven't used EF Core, but I'm pretty sure what you are saying is not correct.  EF is smart enough to do do this all in the same operation.  Otherwise, if you have a requirement that the two changes must either complete or fail entirely, it will get very complicated.

Comment: I am sorry but you should read more carefully. The way #2 of PO shows how you can do it in the same operation. There are just 2 different algoritms. My answer is about why the way#1 is not working.

Comment: Just assign Student property instead of StudentId.

Comment: I understand EF perform  database transaction by default. By adding Stundent entity and use it's primary key on below objects works perfectly on EF6 (I have running codes on production environment). I still don't get why the same algorithm don't work on EF Core. Is there a change in EF Core or was it a bug on EF6? Thanks